# Handling 425 Too Early Error in Axios Request on React App

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm trying to make calls to the server with axios in the first post, it works for me.
Also in the second post.

Then in the second Get I get error 425 (Too Early).

And the code crashes.

How do I fix it?

```
 const handleUpload = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    if (selectedFile && selectedLanguage) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", selectedFile);
      formData.append("language", String(selectedLanguage?.code));
  
      try {
        const baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
  
        // First API call to upload the file
        const uploadResponse = await axios.post(
          `${baseURL}/upload/`,
          formData,
          {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            },
          }
        );
  
        const newId = uploadResponse.data.public_id;
        setSelectedId(newId);
  
        // Second API call to add translation
        const addTranslation = await axios.post(
          `${baseURL}/upload/sources/${newId}/outputs`,
          { language: selectedLanguage.code }
        );
        const newOutputId = addTranslation.data.id;
  
        // Third API call to get the translated content
        try {
          debugger;
          const getTranslation = await axios.get(
            `${baseURL}/upload/outputs/${newOutputId}/contents/`
          );
          const newVideoUrl = getTranslation.data.url;
          setVideoUrl(newVideoUrl);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error fetching translation:", error);
          // Handle error specific to fetching translation
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("File upload failed:", error);
        // Handle general upload error
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    }
  };
```

I tried to use `settimeout`, split the functions, split into different files... it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one is answering the question. I am curious about 425 web communication security.

I don't know if this going to work but it's worth a try.

How about if you automatically retry the request after the delay is complete and still get a 425 error, and continue until the wait time to respond is complete?

```
 try
 {
    const getTranslation = await 
    retryOn425Error(`${baseURL}/upload/outputs/${newOutputId}/contents/`);
    // rest of the code
  }
```

**Here is the retry async function**

```
// change the retries value 
async function retryOn425Error(url, retries = 10, delay = 1000) {
  try {
    return await axios.get(url);
  } catch (error) {
    if (retries > 0 && error.response && error.response.status === 425) {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
      return safeGetRequest(url, retries - 1, delay * 2);
    }
    throw error;
  }
}
```

If you keep getting 425 errors then you might need to look at the server logs to see the error and security configuration